# Overlay on individual icons

Tags: php, html, css

Having trouble putting an overlay over individual icons using PHP for Wordpress. Seems as if the overlay goes over the whole container when used ahead of the repeater loop.

My problem is the placement of the overlay surrounding the PHP but it is affecting the whole container. I need it only to work on the icons echoed onto the site

```
<div class="section widget widget_<?php echo $view; ?> container">


    <div class="icon_row__image container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="icon_image__wrapper ">

                <?php echo $object->icon_row; ?>

                    <?php

            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                if( have_rows('icon_row') ):

                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows('icon_row') ) : the_row(); ?>


                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="col-md-12 overlay">
                                    <div class="overlay-text">Hello 
                                     World</div>
                                </div>

                                <img  src="<?php 
                                the_sub_field('icon_image');?>" 
                                class="icon_image__style" ><p 
                                class="icon_image__text"><?php 
                                the_sub_field('icon_text');?></p>
                           </div>


                        <?php endwhile;

                    else :

                    // no rows found

                    endif;

                    ?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
 }

.icon_row__image:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
}
```

Apologies in advance for the code - still learning.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed php code and replaced with duplicate content for the demo. Here is the code -

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
 }

.col-md-3:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
}

.col-md-3{
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  width : 100px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.col-md-3 img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section widget widget_<?php echo $view; ?> container">


    <div class="icon_row__image container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="icon_image__wrapper ">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-text">Hello World</div>
                    </div>
                    <img  src="https://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Slappy-770x470.png" class="icon_image__style" >
                    <p class="icon_image__text">Random Text</p>
               </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-text">Hello World</div>
                    </div>
                    <img  src="https://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Slappy-770x470.png" class="icon_image__style" >
                    <p class="icon_image__text">Random Text</p>
               </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-text">Hello World</div>
                    </div>
                    <img  src="https://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Slappy-770x470.png" class="icon_image__style" >
                    <p class="icon_image__text">Random Text</p>
               </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is fine but need to make it work with the PHP. its a lot easier to control placement with individual img tags but need to make it work with the WP repeater field

Comment: Dude you were completely right and I am an idiot. I had double overlay on the CSS which i didnt see that you changed. you are a hero! thanks veery much. All working

Comment: Glad to know that. Please don't forget to accept this answer